# Spring-проект не видит таблиц в БД

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Все таблицы созданы, схемы указаны, аннотации с `@Column` висят, но ничего не помогает. Он просто выдает ошибку, что таблицы не существуют, причем названия таблиц абсолютно не те, что я прописывал в классах.
Проект: `Spring MVC + Hibernate + JPA + PostgreSQL`

Order:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_order", schema = "public")
public class Order {

    public Order(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Order(/*Customer customer,*/ String address,
                 String phoneNumber, Date dateOrder, /* Cook cook,*/
                 List<Dish> dishes, boolean orderStatus) { // Базовый конструктор

//        this.customer = customer;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber= phoneNumber;
        this.dateOrder = dateOrder;
//        this.cook = cook;
        this.dishes = dishes;
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;


//    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JsonBackReference
//    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "date_order")
    private Date dateOrder;

//    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JsonBackReference
//    private Cook cook;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private boolean orderStatus;
}
```

Dish:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "dish", schema = "public")
public class Dish {

    public Dish(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Dish(String dishName, double dishCost/*, List<Cook> cookList*/,
                short weight, short cookingTime, String aboutDish) { // Базовый конструктор

        this.dishName = dishName;
        this.dishCost = dishCost;
//        this.cookList = cookList;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.cookingTime = cookingTime;
        this.aboutDish = aboutDish;
    }

    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String dishName;

    @Column(name = "dish_cost")
    private double dishCost;

//    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dish", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JsonManagedReference
//    private List<Cook> cookList;

    @Column(name = "weight")
    private short weight;

    @Column(name = "cooking_time")
    private short cookingTime;

    @Column(name = "about_dish")
    private String aboutDish;

    @ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Order> ordersList;
}
```

app.propertis:

```java
#Pretty Print for Jackson
spring.jackson.serialization.INDENT_OUTPUT=true
#Databse
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tinychiefdelights
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=myPass
```

OrderContr:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.controller;

import com.tinychiefdelights.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Order;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.OrderRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class OrderController {

    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

    public OrderController(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    // Aggregate Root
    @GetMapping("/orders")
    List<Order> all(){
        return orderRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/orders")
    Order newOrder (@RequestBody Order newOrder){
        return orderRepository.save(newOrder);
    }

    //Single Item
    @GetMapping("/orders/{id}")
    Order one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return orderRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
    Order replaceOrder(@RequestBody Order newOrder, @PathVariable Long id){
        return orderRepository.findById(id)
                .map(order -> {
//                    order.setCustomer(newOrder.getCustomer());
                    order.setAddress(newOrder.getAddress());
                    order.setPhoneNumber(newOrder.getPhoneNumber());
                    order.setDateOrder(newOrder.getDateOrder());
//                    order.setCook(newOrder.getCook());
                    order.setDishes(newOrder.getDishes());
                    return orderRepository.save(order);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newOrder.setId(id);
                    return orderRepository.save(newOrder);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/orders/{id}")
    void deleteOrder(@PathVariable Long id){
        orderRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

DishContr:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.controller;

import com.tinychiefdelights.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Dish;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.DishRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class DishController {

    private final DishRepository dishRepository;

    public DishController(DishRepository dishRepository) {
        this.dishRepository = dishRepository;
    }

    // Aggregate Root
    @GetMapping("/dishes")
    List<Dish> all(){
        return dishRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/dishes")
    Dish newDish (@RequestBody Dish newDish){
        return dishRepository.save(newDish);
    }

    //Single Item
    @GetMapping("/dishes/{id}")
    Dish one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return dishRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/dishes/{id}")
    Dish replaceDish(@RequestBody Dish newDish, @PathVariable Long id){
        return dishRepository.findById(id)
                .map(dish -> {
                    dish.setDishName(newDish.getDishName());
                    dish.setDishCost(newDish.getDishCost());
                    dish.setCookingTime(newDish.getCookingTime());
                    dish.setWeight(newDish.getWeight());
                    dish.setAboutDish(newDish.getAboutDish());
//                    dish.setCookList(newDish.getCookList());
                    return dishRepository.save(dish);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newDish.setId(id);
                    return dishRepository.save(newDish);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/dishes/{id}")
    void deleteDish(@PathVariable Long id){
        dishRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```java
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-29 22:47:20.364  INFO 16312 --- [           main] c.t.TinyChiefDelightsApplication         : Starting TinyChiefDelightsApplication on DESKTOP-HAMOHO9 with PID 16312 (D:\TinyChiefDelights\build\classes\java\main started by Артур in D:\TinyChiefDelights)
2020-03-29 22:47:20.367  INFO 16312 --- [           main] c.t.TinyChiefDelightsApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-29 22:47:20.930  INFO 16312 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-29 22:47:20.985  INFO 16312 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 50ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-29 22:47:21.383  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-29 22:47:21.393  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-29 22:47:21.393  INFO 16312 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-29 22:47:21.528  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-29 22:47:21.528  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1116 ms
2020-03-29 22:47:21.624  INFO 16312 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-29 22:47:21.713  INFO 16312 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-29 22:47:21.749  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-29 22:47:21.805  INFO 16312 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-29 22:47:21.902  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-29 22:47:21.983  INFO 16312 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2020-03-29 22:47:22.507  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-29 22:47:22.513  INFO 16312 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-29 22:47:22.750  WARN 16312 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-03-29 22:47:22.849  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-29 22:47:22.962  WARN 16312 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-03-29 22:47:23.040  WARN 16312 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.f.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration    : Cannot find template location(s): [classpath:/templates/] (please add some templates, check your FreeMarker configuration, or set spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false)
2020-03-29 22:47:23.115  INFO 16312 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-29 22:47:23.118  INFO 16312 --- [           main] c.t.TinyChiefDelightsApplication         : Started TinyChiefDelightsApplication in 3.019 seconds (JVM running for 3.713)
2020-03-29 22:47:26.486  INFO 16312 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-29 22:47:26.487  INFO 16312 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-29 22:47:26.492  INFO 16312 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2020-03-29 22:47:26.721  WARN 16312 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2020-03-29 22:47:26.721 ERROR 16312 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ОШИБКА: отношение "pg_order_dishes" не существует
  Позиция: 280
2020-03-29 22:47:26.734 ERROR 16312 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: JSON mapping problem: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.tinychiefdelights.model.Order["dishes"]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.tinychiefdelights.model.Order["dishes"])] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "pg_order_dishes" не существует
  Позиция: 280
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2578) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2313) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2153) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:97) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:921) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:294) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: По идее вам надо создать таблицу pg_order_dishes

Comment: когда я его создаю, у меня выдает следующую ошибку, что я не создал колонку таблицы dishes0_dishes.id. Я вообще не пойму почему он генерирует эти названия. Все таблицы я уже давно создал и указал в коде в аннотациях!

Comment: ИМХО, связи таблиц через аннотации - излишне сложны и нужно иметь очень большой опыт, чтобы сделать то, что нужно. Лично я уже не первый год аннотации для связей не использую. Вместо этого делаю связи вручную, т.е. отдельными запросами наполняю списки связанных объектов в моделях. Что и вам советую.

Comment: Юрий, я наверно неверно выразился. Я так и делаю, все вручную. Ошибку нашел: не добавил @JoinTable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается необходимо было добавить аннотацию `@JoinTable`:

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinTable(name = "pg_order_dish",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Dish> dishes;
```